# Know which type of triangle is in c++

Tags: c++, geometry

Well, I need to make a program that should know which type of triangle is, the user will enter the size of each side of the triangle and then it will print which type of triangle is (scalene, isosceles, equilateral), I'm a very newbie "programmer" (less than half-month), anyway this is what I have:

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;
int main(){

    int num1;
    int num2;
    int num3;

    cout << "first number" << endl;
    cin >> num1;
    cout << "second number" << endl;
    cin >> num2;
    cout << "third number"  << endl;
    cin >> num3;

    if (num1 == num2 == num3){
        cout << "it's equilateral" << endl;
    }

    else if (num1 != num2 != num3){
        cout << "it's scalene" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Why my code doesn't work correctly? for example: I enter 1 for the first, then 1 for the second, then 2 for the third, and it gaves me it's scalene, but if I wrote num1 != num2 != num3, I know this can be stupid but I'm just learning. Thanks.

Comment: Not the cause of your problem, but probably worth considering nevertheless: your example with side lengths `[1, 1, 2]` is not actually a triangle at all (it's a line).

Comment: You also do not check for non-triangles like [-1, 6, 8], [0, 4, 6], or [1, 2, 5].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code to

```
if (num1 == num2 && num2 == num3){
    cout << "it's equilateral" << endl;
}

else if (num1 != num2 || num2 != num3){
    cout << "it's scalene" << endl;
}
```

because when you write `n == m == k` the compiler sees it as `(n==m) ==k`, `n == m` is a boolean value (true or false, 0 or 1). Then it is compared with `k`.

Comment: Your second condition should be `num1 != num2 && num2 != num3`, otherwise isosceles triangles will incorrectly get classified as scalene.

Comment: @Mac, you are right, but I think the author get the idea. Actually we also need to test the equality of num1 and num3.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the 2 expressions:

num1 == num2 == num3 & 
num1 != num2 != num3

if you enter 1, 1, 2

the first expression will be 1 == 1 which is true and the then true == 2 which is false

and for the second expression:

1 != 1 which is false and then false != 3 which is true so you will get the string "scalene"